# Using FIX message timestamps without milliseconds in quickfix/C++

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm working with an initiator app and I've set my configuration file as:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
MillisecondsInTimeStamp=N
...
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.4.2
...
```

But, telling not to add milliseconds in the configuration file takes no effect on the timestamps of the fix messages:

```
...[SOH]52=20180321-21:07:36.848[SOH]...
```

I've also tried to overwrite the tag with no success:

```
FIX::UtcTimeStamp m_time;
m_time.setCurrent();
msg.removeField(52);
msg.setField(52, FIX::UtcTimeStampConvertor::convert(m_time, false));
```

I only get a duplicated 52 tag, although the duplicated one without milliseconds. Anyway, how can I send messages without milliseconds in their timestamps?

Comment: `Tag 52` is in the header of the message. You are adding another tag 52 in the body.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I asked for the header first and then remove and set the field and it worked: `msg.getHeader().removeField(52);  msg.getHeader().setField(52, FIX::UtcTimeStampConvertor::convert(m_time, false));`